# Python Script to build URL with target="blank"

Tags: python, html

I am attempting to build a URL - using Python 2.7 and have the following code:

```
link.append("<a href='" + tableLink + sysID[i] + " target='_blank'>" + ticketNumber[i] + "</a>")
```

For some reason the resulting link on the display UI has everything up to "target=" and then nothing else. I know in the past with other languages there are escapes a double quote with \ or I have done something similar as the above by using single quotes. I'm thinking I must have something fudged up with the quotes during the build of the URL. What I'd like is something like:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

as the final output. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks so much!

Comment: you forgot `'` which ends url in href.

Comment: I think you might have missed a single quote at `" target='_blank'>"`, should it be `"' target='_blank'>"`?

Comment: Doh! I knew it was something simple I just wasn't seeing. Sometimes after trying for a while your eyes get tired and you can't see the forest for the trees. Thanks, all. I would accept all your answers, but I accepted the first one that was posted since you all had the same suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a closing quote on href, try:

`link.append("<a href='" + tableLink + sysID[i] + "' target='_blank'>" + ticketNumber[i] + "</a>")`

I'd also recommend swapping your use of single and double quotes, double quotes are standard for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `'` which ends url in href.

You can use `format()` to make it more readable.

```
link.append('<a href="{}{}" target="_blank">{}</a>'.format(tableLink, sysID[i], ticketNumber[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

When first looking at this, there appears to be an extra single quote in your link.append(), next to href=.

If you want to have the double quotes in your output, I would suggest wrapping your strings in single quotes.  This seems to produce something close to the output you desire:

```
link.append('<a href="' + tableLink + sysID[i] + '" target="_blank">' + ticketNumber[i] + '</a>')
```